# The importance of _gl parameter for cross domain tracking when you have Google Analytics installed

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-ads-api, web-analytics

I have a website and its booking engine (2 different domains) at work and visitors land on the website and then proceed to the booking engine.

I have installed Google Analytics correctly to measure conversions that take place in the booking engine domain. Everything getting recorded correctly in Google Analytics account.

We recently launch Google Ads campaign and I saw that there is another parameter named '_gl' needed to append to the booking engine URL when a visitor proceeds to the booking engine via the website for correct cross domain tracking (probably to avoid Safari tracking prevention).

Just wanted to know, how important this _gl parameter for cross domain tracking since I already have correct Google Analytics setup in place and have linked Google Analytics and Ads accounts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you mention is very important in order to correctly track users between two domains, otherwise GA cannot link the same user when they browse from one domain to another.