# unable to access a specific content on a different website using id attribute from an anchor tag on a different website

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor tag on my website so that when user clicks on it, I can take them to the FAQ page of a different website.

`<a href="https://company.mycompany.com/services/faq/#faq-31" title='My company FAQ' target='_blank' class='urlLink'>at least 5 business days</a>`

For example, currently, since I'm testing locally, my website is the following

`http://localhost:8080/mycompany/abc.htm`

But after deployment, it's going to be a different domain like following:

`https://company.yourcompany.com/abc.htm`

And I'm trying to access the `https://company.mycompany.com/services/faq/#faq-31` site from my local deployment currently.

After clicking on the link and inspecting it in the Browsers developers window, I'm seeing that the link is showing like this:

```
<a href="https://company.mycompany.com/services/faq/?_gl=1*1en21*_ga*MTE2OTQ4MjY4My4xNjgxODM0NTQ2*_ga_F31GQF9LTB*MTY4MjM2NzU0Ny4yMS4xLjE2ODIzNzI5OTQuMC4wLjA.#faq-31" title="My company FAQ" target="_blank" class="urlLink">
at least 5 business days</a>
```

What is that stuff added before `#faq-31` in the URL?

By the way, I tried testing `https://company.mycompany.com/services/faq/#faq-31` from my computer browser, but it only loads the page as if I've just clicked `https://company.mycompany.com/services/faq`

Any idea if what I'm trying to achieve is possible?

Comment: Your website has Google Analytics `<script>` and it's adding tracking junk to your links, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021450/the-importance-of-gl-parameter-for-cross-domain-tracking-when-you-have-google-a

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that I won't be able to access the content using its id attribute?

Comment: Are you certain that the fragment reference is valid? It is case-sensitive - and the browser viewport won't necessarily scroll-down unless the target element is off-screen, so if it's above-the-fold you might not see anything at all.

Comment: It looks like the reference is valid. When I inspect a particular content on the target website which is a list like this `<li id="faq-5" style="display: block; transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;" data-slide-toggle="true">Text goes here.</li>` and even if I try to access the website like this `https://company.mycompany.com/services/faq/#faq-5`, it won't scroll down or take me to that particular list item